# Java JAXB marshall into DOM Document

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xmldom

I have JAXB annotations:

```
@XmlElement(name="String")
private String string = "one";

@XmlElement(name="ArrayOne")
private ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and marshalling:

```
array.add("Just one");
JAXBContext jc1 = JAXBContext.newInstance( getClass() );
Marshaller marshaller = jc1.createMarshaller();
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance() ; 
Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
marshaller.marshal(this, doc);
```

If I dig into document nodes, I cannot see any difference between 
node elements.
My question is, if there is any trick how to marshall into DOM document,
that node elements will be somehow distinct, whether is simple object(String),
or array object. Marshaller of course is aware of field types, so I wonder,
if it puts some flag in Element data.

DOM structure is

```
NodeName:String     NodeContent:one
NodeName:ArrayOne   NodeContent:Just one
```

but I would like to have like:

```
NodeName:String     NodeContent:one
NodeName:ArrayOne
    Children:
    NodeName:ArrayOne   NodeContent:Just one
```

so I know, ArrayOne is array, no matter of just one object.

Note, that I cannot change annotations, since there is not always source available.

Answer (score 2):

You can create wrapper element for collections using *@XmlElementWrapper*:

```
@XmlElement(name="String")
private String string = "one";

@XmlElementWrapper(name="ArrayOne")
private ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

XML output for this mapping looks like this:

```
<testElement>
    <String>one</String>
    <ArrayOne>
        <array1>one</array1>
    </ArrayOne>
</testElement>
```

**Update for comment**:
Adding wrapper on DOM Document manually (probably there is an easier way, maybe by using a Transformer):

```
TestElement te = new TestElement();

JAXBContext jc1 = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestElement.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jc1.createMarshaller();
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance() ;
Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
marshaller.marshal(te, doc);

NodeList nodeList = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
Node newNode = doc.createElement("ArrayOneWrapper");
List<Node> arrayOneElements = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node n = nodeList.item(i);

    if (n.getNodeName().equals("ArrayOne")) {
        arrayOneElements.add(n);
    }
}
for (Node n : arrayOneElements) {
    newNode.appendChild(n);
}
```

XML output:

```
<testElement>
    <String>one</String>
    <ArrayOneWrapper>
        <ArrayOne>one</ArrayOne>
        <ArrayOne>two</ArrayOne>
    </ArrayOneWrapper>
</testElement>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need it without changing annotations :)
There is no always source code for the objects to marshall.
And I dont need XML output, just DOM document, cause I have other intentions with it :) You think there cannot be something to provide marshaller before marshalling into DOM to do similar ?

Comment: The XML is generated from DOM Document, i used it just to show how elements are wrapped. I do not have idea currently how to do it without annotations.